# XPath: Select first 5 elements

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

At the moment I am scraping some data from another website and I'm having problems about how to get the first 5 elements only.

```
$travelguide_row = 
$travelguide_xpath->query('//div[@class="traveltips"]//span|//div[@class="traveltips"]//p');
```

Can I add more syntaxes after `//span` and `//p`?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use predicate expression `[position() < 6]` to achieve that. The following XPath should get you the first 5 elements matched by your original XPath expression :

```
(//div[@class="traveltips"]//span|//div[@class="traveltips"]//p)[position() < 6]
```

Comment: I have tried that expression but I didn't know I could put my own code in parentheses! :) Thanks a lot! I have learnt something again.